# Python replace empty strings in a list of string using List Comprehension

Tags: python-3.x, replace

I have a list like this

```
test1 = ['a', 'b', 'c', '', 'd']
```

and i expect to replace the '' with "hello"

```
test2 = [w.replace('', 'test') for w in test1 ]
```

output: `['a', 'b', 'c', '', 'd']`

So, how to use list Comprehension to make it?

Comment: Welcome to SO! I don't quite follow what you're attempting to do here, nor does my output match yours. I see `['testatest', 'testbtest', 'testctest', 'test', 'testdtest']` rather than `['a', 'b', 'c', '', 'd']` as your post states. Can you clarify your intent?

Comment: Oh, you're right, if i run  test2 = [w.replace('', 'test') for w in test1 ], output just like you see, I expect to replace the '' to 'test', do you know how to make it? :)

Answer (score 3):

a list comprehension would be:

```
[t if t is not '' else 'hello' for t in test1]
```

Answer (score 1):

```
test1 = ['a', 'b', 'c', '', 'd']
for n in range(len(test1)):
  if not test1[n]:
    test1[n] = 'hello'
```

An empty string has a false value, you could also use `test1[n] == ''`

Answer (score 1):

something along the lines of:

```
x = ['a', 'b', 'c', '', 'd']

['hello' if s=='' else s for s in x]

['a', 'b', 'c', 'hello', 'd']
```